# Add side menu on child view of an Ionic side menu app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I want to add side menu on the child view of my side menu app. How can I possible this task? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of examples, just take look on this on hopes it will help you [example](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSideMenus/)

for more examples google "code pen ion-side-menus"

Comment: Thank you @italy Menchikovsky

Comment: if this is your answer please do it as answer.